# How to use faker to generate a point?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

I have a model with the following attribute:

```
#  lonlat         :geography({:srid point, 4326
```

Using Faker, how can I create a value for this?

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :my_table do
    # ...
    lonlat { }
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation of Faker, to build coordinates to can use:

```
lon = Faker::Address.longitude
lat = Faker::Address.latitude
```

Here you can find all the methods of Faker:
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/stympy/faker/index

If you use `activerecord-postgis-adapter` you can use provided factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :my_table do
    # ...
    lonlat { factory.point(lon, lat) }
    # ...
  end
end
```

More:
https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter#working-with-spatial-data

Answer (score 2):

You don’t specifically say what these are going to be used for, so I can’t tell you exactly how to build your `lonlat` object, but you can use the following to build your coordinates.

Latitude is a number between -90 and 90, and Longitude is a number between -180 and 180, so this will give you a valid coordinate pair, which you can then use as you please.

```
lat = rand(-90.0..90.0)
lon = rand(-180.0..180.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

model name :Point.
db column name :latitude,longitude.

in seed.rb

```
factory :points do
  latitude { Faker::Address.latitude }
  longitude { Faker::Address.longitude }
end
```

then in terminal

```
rake db:seed
```

Answer (score 0):

Faker also offers [`full_address_as_hash`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/stympy/faker/Faker/Address#full_address_as_hash-class_method) in the `Faker::Address` class which you can pass just the arguments that you want.  In this case a pair of Lat / Long points

```rb
Faker::Address.full_address_as_hash(:latitude, :longitude) # => {:latitude=>85.02775596916655, :longitude=>127.31271466578505}
```